# How to download video in youtube whose name length is larger than 255 bytes?

Tags: bash, youtube

In most linux system the file name is limited to maximum of 255 bytes.

```
getconf -a | grep -i name_max
NAME_MAX                           255
_POSIX_NAME_MAX                    255
LOGNAME_MAX                        256
TTY_NAME_MAX                       32
TZNAME_MAX                         6
_POSIX_TZNAME_MAX                  6
CHARCLASS_NAME_MAX                 2048
HOST_NAME_MAX                      64
LOGIN_NAME_MAX                     256
```

I find that some videos' name length in youtube is larger than 255 bytes ,how to download that kind of video and keep the long name unchaged as downloaded file's name?
`youtube-dl $url` can't work for the long name video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following `youtube-dl` options:

- --id
- --output
- --restrict-filenames

The `--id` limits filenames to using the video id, `--output` lets you specify a template for naming the output file. Using `--restrict-filenames` will ensure filenames are script and shell friendly.

Have a look at the help section entitled `OUTPUT TEMPLATE` to see how templates work, an example is:

```
$ youtube-dl --output '%(title)s.%(ext)s' BaW_jenozKc --restrict-filenames
```

You may also find the `--get-filename` option useful. It will show you the filename that will be used without actually downloading it.